# Coordinates of a point with respect to a reference coordinate system

Tags: matrix, camera, computer-vision, kinect, camera-calibration

So I have a camera that I am using to obtain the camera coordinates (coordinates of the object w.r.t. the camera) of an object infront of it. So I was able to achieve that.

So now I want to find the coordinates of that object with respect to a coordinate system that I laid down on the ground. (reference coordinate/world coordinates)

I understand its just a rotation/translation matrix.

I am having a hard time obtaining this matrix. Any one has any idea of how I can go about to do that?

So I basically have the XYZ camera coordinates of my target object and the axes that I laid down to act as my reference coordinate system

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have:

- a set of XYZ coordinates that belongs to your object's tracked features wrt to camera.
- the XYZ coordinates of the same features in some CAD (or world) reference frame (design coordinates).

You can obtain the rotation and translation by computing the optimal rotation between these paired set of point coordinates, using the Kabsch algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm

So, basically you:

1. get the centroid of each coordinate set [XYZ]_i, where i= 1, 2.
2. de-centroid each coordinate (subtract each centroid from each [XYZ])
3. form a covariance matrix (call it C)
4. Apply SVD to the covariance matrix [U,S,V] = svd(C)
5. Rotation = V*U', where, ' is the transpose operator
6. translation = -R * centroid_of_[XYZ]_1 + centroid_of_[XYZ]_2

There is a nice guide about finding this rotation~translation pair here: http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a calibration procedure to identify common 2 points of your laid coordinate system. This cannot be done only using Kinect. You will have to put a physical points to identify your x,y coordinates system. For example you can fix a vertical pole on your 0,0 coordinate and once you touch that pole you can get the respective Kinect coordinate for that physical pole now this kinect coordinate  is your relative 0,0 in computer space. Now any point you find in computer space has to recalculate to the relative point you found.